# Implicit conversion warning int to int-lookalike

Tags: c++, type-conversion, compiler-warnings, signed, truncation

My compiler warms me about a lot of implicit conversion:

Some I do understand, like

```
implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'std::vector::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long')`
```

when I do `myvector.resize(myInt)`  .

Other more obscure, like

```
implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'
```

when I do `myInt=myString.size()`, or

```
implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long')
```

when I call `myString[myInt]`

I all cases, I do understand why I get these message (int-uint, etc), however their use is non-ambiguous in the program. What do I risk if I do not hunt change the type of my variables to delete these warning?  My previous compiler didn't warn me of anything, so when I changed my PC I suddenly had dozens of warning.

Comment: A general rule is to use a variable for only one purpose. Then you can always make it the correct type.

Comment: I get the feeling that I always have to cast (int to uint, or int to double), so I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Another good general rule is to forget that cast exists.

Comment: If you have to cast, you are *usually* "doing it wrong".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I all cases, I do understand why I get these message (int-uint, etc),
> however their use is non-ambiguous in the program. What do I risk if I
> do not hunt change the type of my variables to delete these warning?

It's not about ambiguity.  If you convert a signed value to an unsigned type, you may get bizarre results:

```
long i = -2147483645;        // for example

std::vector<int> vec{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
std::cout << vec[i] << "\n"; // undefined behavior, not always caught
```

Here, assuming a 32-bit system, `i` gets converted to `2147483651` before it is passed to `operator[]`, causing undefined behavior.

If you are *really* sure the conversion is harmless, you can do a `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<std::vector<int>::size_type>(i)
```

> My previous compiler didn't warn me of anything, so when I changed my
> PC I suddenly had dozens of warning.

**Always turn on warnings.**  At least do `-Wall`.  When writing libraries, I tend to make sure my code compiles cleanly even with `-Wextra`.  They can help you catch a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 2):

The size_type of the stl boils down to an `unsigned long` for your compiler. That issues the `implicit conversion changes signedness` warning when assigning it to a signed type like `int`.

Additionally the width of a `long` depends on the cpu architecture, i.e. it 32 Bit on x86 but 64 Bit on x64, whereas an `int` is defined to 32 Bit width. This issues the `implicit conversion loses integer precision` warning.

> My previous compiler didn't warn me of anything, so when I changed my
>   PC I suddenly had dozens of warning

Probably the warning level on your new PC is higher. Check thecompiler options for `-W3` (Windows), `-Wall` or `-Wextra` (GCC).

> What do I risk if I do not hunt change the type of my variables to
>   delete these warning?

It's at least bad style and causes undefined behaviour if the size of the stl container does not fit into an int.